# 'dateCreated' field not displaying in view in grails

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am learning Grails(grails-2.3.7) and started following a book "GettingStartedwithGrailsFinalInfoQ". My Domain class content is :

```
package grailsdemo

class Registration {

    String name
    Date dateOfBirth
    String gender
    String address
    String city
    String state
    String zipcode
    String email
    Date dateCreated   //Note: this is a special name

    static constraints = {

              }

    static belongsTo = [race:Race]

    static mapping = {
      autoTimestamp false
    }
}
```

And the respective Controller class code is :

```
   package grailsdemo

class RegistrationController {

    def scaffold = true
}
```

The problem is that the field 'dateCreated' is not displayed in the view.
The same code is working in the book example.
My view :[image]

Book view : [image]

Answer (score 0):

The book is quite old, and uses Grails 1.2. 
Both dateCreated, lastUpdated, id and version are special fields in Grails, and are treated so in the scaffolded views.

You can see how the scaffolded code looks like when you run grails generate-all grailsdemo.Registration
for the particular version of Grails that you are using.

For a more recent book using grails 2.3.7, I can reecommend "Grails in Action" by Glen Smith and Peter Ledbrook

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But is there any way to display the 'dateCreated' field ?? If possible ..

Comment: There is always a way :) You can use `grails install-templates`
And edit the files in `src/templates/scaffolding`to include dateCreated for any domain class, if you need it included in general.